# Apps launch but are not visible and desktop freezes

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, gui, desktop-environments

Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 LTS

For example if I open the Terminal app the Terminal window doesn't appear but the mouse pointer does change to a cursor when hovering over the area of the desktop where the terminal window should be.

The mouse pointer can still be moved around the screen but clicking has no effect.

Keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> do not work.

Tried the following but these have not resolved the problem:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell
sudo apt purge gnome-shell
sudo apt install gnome-shell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I found someone with a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306700/fixing-gpu-hang-caused-by-i915-driver).

Using `dmesg | grep GPU` I confirmed my issue is indeed a GPU hang.

```
[  980.100449] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 7:1:85ddfffd, in Xorg [3664]
[  980.204709] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Xorg[3664] context reset due to GPU hang
```

As a temporary solution, until the Intel drivers have been updated, I've added `nomodeset` to my Grub configuration. [Relevant instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/cs-cz/000123893/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

appending `i915.enable_psr=0` to `/etc/default/grub` GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and `sudo update-grub2` then reboot

**Don't use nomodeset, it won't load any driver if you do it**