# Xubuntu freezes when trying to launch discord

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, login, freeze

I'm running the latest LTS of Xubuntu on my machine with 4 GB of RAM.

Whenever I try to launch Discord, which I installed through the Snap Store, it freezes and either forces me to reboot or loops back to login.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: What if you install the regular, non-snap discord?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, with the .deb downloaded from discord. I had no such problems with 18.04.

My biggest clue was that vlc was also crashing the same way. Can you watch video using vlc? If you check your logs (/var/log/Xorg.0.log or /var/log/kern.log) do you see anything about a gpu crash?

The solution for me was to edit /etc/default/grub and change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

I'll let someone with more Ubuntu experience than me explain what that does. Apparently there's a bug in the latest video drivers for Intel GPUs.

Relevant post:
[Apps launch but are not visible and desktop freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306095/apps-launch-but-are-not-visible-and-desktop-freezes)